How to access object instances via python
I want to simulate a laser sensor and export the simulated data. I managed to get the simulation part working, but now I don't know how to export the simulated data.
The laser is simulated using geometry nodes. With the nodes, a mesh is generated and for each vertex of the mesh, a ray is casted. The intersection of each ray is used as a point as a location for a displacement (instance).
Now, in the spreadsheet I get the data under instances, but I'm unable to access it via python and to export it.
How do I manage to access the locations of the instances via python?


Find object instances with python
